# linqjs group by multiple levels

Tags: javascript, linq, group-by, linq.js

I am trying to figure out how to group by at multiple levels:

Given the following input JSON:

```
[
{
    "GroupingMajor": "Fruit",
    "Grouping": "Banana",
    "Description": "10 Bananas",
    "Price": 20609.82,
},
{
    "GroupingMajor": "Fruit",
    "Grouping": "Apple",
    "Description": "13 Apples",
    "Price": 4567.98,
},
{
    "GroupingMajor": "Dairy",
    "Grouping": "Cheese",
    "Description": "1 KG",
    "Price": 76456.76,
}
```

]

I would like to create output of type:

```
{
"name": "root",
"children": [
{
    "name": "Fruit",
    "children": [
        {
            {"name": "Apple", "price": 4567.98},
            {"name": "Banana", "price": 20609.82}
    }]
},
{
    "name": "Dairy",
    "children": [
        {
            {"name": "Cheese", "price": 76456.76}
    }]
}]
```

}

That is, data is grouped by "GroupingMajor" and then "Grouping". "Grouping" being a child of the parent "GroupingMajor" category. How can I generate this output using linq.js (JavaScript)?

Here is some JavaScript that I've attempted:

```
var data = Enumerable.From(dataFood)
                     .GroupBy(
                            function (e) { 
                                return { 
                                    groupmajor: e.GroupingMajor,
                                    groupminor: e.Grouping
                                }},
                            function (e) {                          
                                return {
                                    groupmajor: e.GroupingMajor,
                                    groupminor: e.Grouping,
                                    name: e.GroupingMajor,
                                    price: e.Price,
                                }
                            },
                            function (key, g) {
                                return {
                                    group: key.groupmajor,
                                    groupminor: key.groupminor,
                                    name: g.name,
                                    price: g.price
                                }
                            })
                        .ToArray();
```

I am not getting a correct grouping and I have no idea how to generate a sub-group.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how you could construct such a query:

```
var query = Enumerable.From(data)
    .GroupBy(
        "$.GroupingMajor", // key
        "{ name: $.Grouping, price: $.Price }", // item
        "{ name: $, children: $$.ToArray() }" // result
    )
    .ToArray();
var result = {
    name: 'root',
    children: query
};
```

Which would yield the following result:

```
{
  "name": "root",
  "children": [
    {
      "name": "Fruit",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Banana",
          "price": 20609.82
        },
        {
          "name": "Apple",
          "price": 4567.98
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "Dairy",
      "children": [
        {
          "name": "Cheese",
          "price": 76456.76
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```